# ZBarScanner camera preview got green bars

Tags: android, camera, preview, galaxy

In Android SDK, some S4 device facing this when I go for QRCode scanning:
http://www.pohrani.com/f/J/Hw/DKC8eLS/2014-01-08-131409.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shockingly, on some S4 devices "setPreviewSize" from camera parameters cause the scanning page looks like that!